# I possibly need someone who knows about C++ to translate me a chinese article which would solve my current problem. Where do I ask this question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am not sure where to put this question in, so I prefer to ask here first.

Currently, I am trying to solve an issue with C++ / WTL, and after quite some research I only found a chinese article with a possible solution:

```
注意Member type需要手工输入 CHyperLink

DDX type必须使用Control，不能使用Control Handler。否则编译时会出现下面错误。

Error 1 error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'ATL::CWindow' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

from [this Website](http://www.cnblogs.com/procoder/archive/2009/11/12/Windows-Mobile-WTL-HyperLink.html)

However, I don't even speak the slightest of chinese. I tried translating it, but I feel like there's quite a lot of important technical context missing, and I can't work with what I am given by translation.

Where would I ask this question? I don't think stackoverflow would be a proper place for that?

Comment: Here's a tag on [chinese.se] which called [**translation**](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/tags/translation/info), and it says: "Translation questions are not for asking things that you could answer yourself by looking into a dictionary or doing a simple search on the internet – this is not a translation service. When you ask a question like this, please show that you've already done some research, and explain what else you need to know."

Comment: Anyways, I can tell you that it means: Remember that you need enter *CHyperLink* manually in/on(not sure) *Member type*. You need use *Control* in/on *DDX type*, not *Control Handler*. Otherwise it'll raise the following error. `Error 1 error C2679: [...]`. I don't know anything about C++/WTL, so there's something I'm not sure that I'm correct or not. But I think you could understand.

Comment: Oh, just checked the website and it's: "Remember that you need enter *CHyperLink* manually in the *Member type* form [...]" or something like  it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no site within the Stack Exchange network that offers translation services.

As pointed out by [Kevin Guan](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/305595/kevin-guan):

> There is a tag on [Chinese Language](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/) which is called [translation](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/tags/translation/info), and it says:
>
> > Translation questions are not for asking things that you could answer yourself by looking into a dictionary or doing a simple search on the internet – this is not a translation service. When you ask a question like this, please show that you've already done some research, and explain what else you need to know.

In that sense you can't ask that question on any proper SE site.

What you can do is ask a question about your actual code problem on Stack Overflow, providing a good [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), clearly explaining what the errors, what you already tried to fix it and show your research.

Let me expand a bit on how you can include research. You can share the search terms you used in Google, Bing, Yandex or Baidu and which results you already checked. Explain why those didn't answer your question. You can include the link to the Chinese website, stating that you expect the answer to your question is on that page.

With that information, users can reconstruct your issue, come up with a better search term, are able to read the provided link or just happen to know the answer.

If you feel you have not enough information to share you could try a chat room but make sure the room is open for either translation requests or support with your specific issue.